# How to read and post to Facebook Buy, Sell, Trade groups with the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't find any documentation regarding posting to/reading a Facebook Buy, Sell, Trade group, specifically the group specific post attributes such as price, title, sold/unsold, etc.

Does this ability exist within the Graph API, and if so, what are the fields or edges required?

Comment: hi @Lochlan Broughton did you find any answer,i am also have same problem.

Answer (score -3):

This is what you can get from groups: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/group

The API reference tells you exactly what you can get, and how.

There may not be any possibility to deal with buy/sell groups with the API yet.

Comment: Hi luschn, that is not true. Facebook groups can be set as a 'Buy, Sell, Trade' group in the group settings. Other group types include 'close friends' or 'study group'.

Comment: ok, then it must be something very new. either way, the link in my answer tells you exactly what you can get from groups, and how to get it.